# Method can not initialize value c++

Tags: c++, reference, bellman-ford

Firstly I initialize value in constructor in Ford Bellman claas

```
FordBellman::FordBellman() {
    this->vertexCount=0;
    this->vertexFirst=0;
    this->edgeCount=0;
    this->wage=0;
    this->matrix=0;
    this->distance=0;
    this->predecessor=0;

}
```

next I have reference in argument of initialize method in FordBellman

```
void FordBellman::initialize(const AdjacencyMatrix &am)
{
    this->vertexCount=am.getVertexCount();
    this->vertexFirst=am.getVertexFirst();
    this->edgeCount=am.getEdgeCount();
    this->wage=am.getWage();
    this->matrix=am.getMatrix();
    cout << vertexCount;
    cout << vertexFirst;
.....
}
```

in main class I do it in this way

```
int main() {
    AdjacencyMatrix am;
    FordBellman fb;
    am.createFromFile("matrix.txt");
    fb.initialize(am);

}
```

And if i call fb.initialize(am) console show nothing(should show cout ) 
Can you tell me what I do wrong ?

repo https://github.com/likoms/Graph/

Comment: Maybe you should flush the stream once in a while? E.g. add `std::cout << flush;`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I dont think so because in Dijkstry class this solution work fine and i don't know what's gone on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to run code from github repository about you sad I got segmentation fault. The reason was in the file FordBellman.cpp line 42. There you didn't allocate array but you used it.

The reason why you didn't see anything is in the fact your program is terminated before it prints something. To be accurate it's happening inside of `am.createFromFile("matrix.txt");`

Try to write memory allocation for `predecessor` and I think your code will start working.

I'm a bit confused that you doesn't get message about segmentation fault. What development environment you use?

Comment: Actually now there is no any github repositories in comments. But I strongly remember that it was.

Comment: It's posted in the main question now, so you're OK.

Comment: @Nolane I added repo. 
Thank you so much. What compilator you use ? I use eclipse and gcc.

Comment: @PiotrSterna Usually I use clang. It seems you use Visual Studio compiler because I saw #pragma once in your code. Am I right? But I was wondered that you also use #ifndef to avoid duplicating of header. It seems wrong.

Comment: @Nolane I just thought that it's headre problem so i used #pragma once. I code in Linux in Eclipse CDT. I use gcc to compile.